# The Fubini identity in time dependent domain

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to ask a interesting question

Given $0 \leq t \leq T$ and $0 \leq x \leq s(t)$ where $s(t)$ be a given positive function. How we can change the double integral:

$\int_{0}^{T}\int_{0}^{s(t)}f(x,t) dx dt $ to the double integral $\int_{0}^{s(T)}\int_{0}^{T}f(x,t)dt dx$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

If $s\colon[0,T]\to[s(0),s(T)]$ is a bijection (let's say increasing), then
$$
\int_{0}^{T}\int_{0}^{s(t)}f(x,t)\,dx\,dt=\int_{0}^{s(0)}\int_{0}^{T}f(x,t)\,dt\,dx+\int_{s(0)}^{s(T)}\int_{s^{-1}(x)}^{T}f(x,t)\,dt\,dx.
$$

[image]